# Select front page and blog page in custom theme settings page

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

Im creating a theme which have a custom setting page. I know the best method to choose a static page is by going to Settings -> Reading, but my client wants to have all in the same place.

I already got the dropdowns on the settings page and i did the front page by creating the **front-page.php** file and added

```
$options=get_option('pa_opciones');
<? query_posts( 'page_id='.$options['front_page'] ); ?>
```

This is working but im not sure if its the best method or cleanest method. Im trying to make a nice new theme using get_template_parts ,etc.

How should i proceed with the blog page?

currently on my page.php i got:

```
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And on my index.php:

```
get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>



                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>


            <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No se encuentra la pagina', 'defotografos' ); ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p><?php _e( 'Lo sentimos pero no se puede encontrar lo que busca. tal vez si realiza una b&uacute;squeda podr&aacute; encontrar algo similar.', 'defotografos' ); ?></p>
                        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </article><!-- #post-0 -->

            <?php endif; ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Im trying to make all these nice and clean but im getting a bit lost.

Thanks for your comments and suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the *front page displays* setting as set under settings > reading is stored in the options table under `show_on_front`, with value either `posts` or `page`.

if page is selected, the selected pages are stored in options `page_on_front` and `page_for_posts`, with the id of the selected pages as value.

you can update these options yourself from your settings page.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mile for putting me in the right direction, i need to play a bit more with update_option function!